# Is it possible to use the Chrome's devtools when running with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Python code that runs a Chrome instance with Selenium web-driver.

In the past, I was able to use the same code and open Chrome's devtools (the inspector, console and the network tabs specifically) while using the webdriver.

I understood that the new chromedriver (I just upgraded it to 2.3.1) is unable to run parallel to the devtools..

I am seeking a way to use the chrome's devtools parallel in order to debug my code. Does someone know a way to do that?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: one option is using IDE debugging facilities. mark the line of code with break points and execute them in debug mode. then you can use devtools.

Comment: Thats nice but I can't debug the network tab in this scenario..

Comment: This is now possible, as of Chrome 63. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197757/1669860).

Answer (score 2):

As of Chrome 63, this is now possible. See [Multi-client remote debugging support](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#multi-client).

Go to `chrome://version` to check what version of Chrome you're on. Chrome updates every 6 weeks, usually. So if you're on Chrome 62, it'll take up to 6 weeks (maximum) to get Chrome 63.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, once you start working with the DevTools, ChromeDriver stops working because It has been disconnected.
You can find more information regarding this issue on their official website [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing).

Comment: please add actual reason, and provide external links.